# Mouse click on specific time JAVA

Tags: java, datetime, onclick, timezone, mouse

I have small question, how to create mouse clicker, simple mouse clicker just to make one click on exact time.

Please do not minus the topic, I just not really understand how to do it, any help, like where to read click on exact time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question shows zero ability to google and zero intentions of searching for information yourself. I won't play into that by giving you complete code...

You use the java.awt.Robot class to do mouse clicks.

You use a java.util.Timer or java.swing.Timer object to time it.

Comment: Ye, that was good information for me, thx )

Comment: After press button using "java.util.Timer or java.swing.Timer" can press the button for example at 21:01???

Comment: Yes, but I answered in your other thread too.

Answer (score 0):

Use Robot class in java.awt.Robot.
Inside that class are methods for simulating user Clicks, KeyEvents and more. and in conjunction with java.util.Timer